# Windows 7 copy all user files

Tags: windows-7

I want to copy just the user files from my internal 2.5" hdd to an external hdd. I don't need any of the installed programs, just user files like documents, downloads, the user's profile, and related items. Is there an easy way of doing this? I need the proposed program to be able to run in Safe Mode as well.

Comment: The easy way would be to view the contents of your profile in explorer and copy the files you want to migrate.

Comment: @Ramhound yer that's what I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XCOPY or XXCOPY with a DOS command like this:

XCOPY C:\USERS\MYNAME*.* E:\USERS\MYNAME /E /C /I /Y

XXCOPY C:\USERS\MYNAME*.* E:\USERS\MYNAME /BI

Both XCOPY and XXCOPY are DOS commands. Being DOS commands, if there are any spaces in the directory names, you should put them in quotes, e.g..

XXCOPY "C:\USRS\MY NAME*.*" "E:\USERS\MY NAME" /BI

XCOPY comes with Windows. Help is available if you type XCOPY /? from a DOS prompt. XXCOPY can do much more but you need to download and install it. The /BI switch means "incremental backup". Download it and get help from [XXCOPY's website](http://www.xxcopy.com/). Once installed, XXCOPY /? also gives help.

As they run from a DOS prompt, both commands are available in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer  for a task such as this. It allows you to select the items you want and such.